# Does 0x still have the condensed RFQ order type, and if so where is its structure defined?

Tags: 0x

I am looking into the 0x docs at the moment, and get a 404 error when attempting to view the RFQ order type structure in the [cheat sheet section](https://0x.org/docs/introduction/0x-cheat-sheet). Where can I find this order type's struct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why the documentation has a 404 for the page, it indeed does. At the time of writing, I believe this is the struct you're looking for

```
struct RfqOrder {
    IERC20Token makerToken;
    IERC20Token takerToken;
    uint128 makerAmount;
    uint128 takerAmount;
    address maker;
    address taker;
    address txOrigin;
    bytes32 pool;
    uint64 expiry;
    uint256 salt;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/fd68edb23957ddef3e462bf1718d2ea9c3ef93f1/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/libs/LibNativeOrder.sol#L53C1-L65C1